# Bundler failed on gem package em-udns -v '0.3.6.2' install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, rbenv, asdf

When I am trying to run bundle install on macOs , I got error on

```
An error occurred while installing em-udns (0.3.6.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install em-udns -v '0.3.6.2' --source '{sourcepath}'` succeeds before bundling.
```

After the open of log files I am find the

```
"tar zxf /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.9/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/em-udns-0.3.6.2/ext/udns-0.4-patched.tar.gz"
./configure
configure... udns package
checking for C compiler... gcc
checking whenever C compiler (gcc) is GNU CC... yes
checking whenever the C compiler (gcc -Wall -W -O2 -pipe)
           can produce executables... yes
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for getopt()... yes
checking for libraries needed for socket and connect... not found
configure: fatal: cannot find libraries needed for sockets**
```

how can I fix the issue ?